# What is a female ass called?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, animals

I know a male ass is a *jackass*, but what is a female ass called? Perusal of the internet suggests *jillass* or *janeass*, but I haven't found what might be called an authoritative source.

Comment: ..... an assette ;)

Comment: This question made me lol.

Comment: BADONKADONK I’m so sorry.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A [*jenny*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenny_%28donkey%29).

Answer (score 8):

A [jenny ass](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/jenny+ass).